# How to pass url parameters without showing them to the end user in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I want to pass a url parameter in salesforce, but it shouldn't be visible to the end user in the url. Is it possible? Please suggest if there are any other alternatives? Thanks in advance.

In my scenario, I am dealing with 2 pages with individual controllers. In one of the page I am dealing with apex tabs. So I want to get the current tab name. I found the solution for this as passing it into to the url.

Comment: Hi @user3007017, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to pass parameters between pages using the URL, you can do this using form parameters which will "hide" the values from the user (nothing displayed in the URL) like this:

```
<apex:param name="contIdParam" value="{!cont.id}" assignTo="{!contIdChosen}"/>
```

This article may be helpful: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html

Comment: This is for same page, communication between Page and Contrroller. I want it between different VF pages. That is from controller of one VF to other VF.